# Can't get small caps to work when defining specific font file in fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec, small-caps, truetype

I am trying to use specific font files using `fontspec` that are not in my known path.

```
\setmainfont
[Path = Fonts/Cormorant_Garamond/,
ItalicFont = CormorantGaramond-Italic,
BoldFont = CormorantGaramond-Bold,
BoldItalicFont = CormorantGaramond-BoldItalic,
SmallCapsFont = Cormorant-SmallCaps]
{CormorantGaramond-Regular.ttf}
```

I have tried scouring this site for an answer to my issue but have not found anything that works. I am able to get bold and italic fonts using the above code, but not small caps. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `font family name` (`Cormorant Garamond`), not the `file name`. The following example code works with the `.otf` version of the fonts. Note this font has small caps in regular and boldface, but not in italic and bold  italic, as you see with  `otfinfo`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Cormorant Garamond}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers = {OldStyle,Proportional}}

\begin{document}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{There was a young person of Crete}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  There was a Young Person of \textsc{Crete},\\
  Whose toilette was far from complete;\\
  \bfseries
  She dressed in a sack,\\
  Spickle-speckled with black,\\
  That ombliferous person of \textsc{Crete}.\\[2ex]
  \makebox[\versewidth][r]{\mdseries
    Edward \textsc{Lear}}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]